# Button as link which pass parameters

Tags: forms, button, hyperlink

I have this link which pass the parameter.

```
   <a href="?spalte=7">Malvenfroh City  <br> </a>
```

But I want that this whole thing is a button but in this case it doesnt work, why?:

```
<form action="?spalte=7">
    <input type="submit" value="Malvenfroh City">
</form>
```

Have someone another solution ?

Comment: Not sure what MySQL, or SQL has to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the parameters as a hidden input inside the form, here is an example:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="spalte" value="7">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I hope this helps.